# my amp has a buzz

Tags: buzz

I own a squier bronco bass and a fender rumble 40 amp. The amp has a buzz when the bass is plugged in and not plugged in. When I turn the volume up the buzz gets louder. I tried a different power outlet in my house and got the same result. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Does it reduce if you touch a finger to any external metal parts of the amp [the jack socket surround, if that's metal]? Is your mains supply properly earthed?

Comment: when I touch the jack socket the buzz lightens but is still there. And how do I know the main supply is probably earthed?

Comment: Well, if the plug has 3 pins is one clue. If you're in the UK, the socket is earthed, by law. Most other countries seem to just have a very cavalier attitude to electrical safety, so you'd have to ask an electrician.

Comment: so the amp is the problem or the amp cord?

Comment: You haven't answered my first & most important question yet. Is it earthed properly? If it isn't, then that's very likely the fix.

Comment: what is being earthed?

Comment: (If you do not connect a [UFO](https://www.musicradar.com/reviews/guitars/homebrew-electronics-ufo-603192) pedal, it is likely to be earthed ;). )

Comment: I do not own a ufo pedal

Comment: Sometimes the UFOs own you…

Comment: If you can't test for the grounding (earthed) maybe you could take your gear to a friends house and see if the buzzing remains the same. If it goes away, then it's likely a grounding issue as Tetsujin has identified. If it's still there, your equipment should be taken to a luthier for a though check over.